# ReflectionException Class Not Found on Laravel Repository

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I'm getting a reflection exception thrown on a repository. I simply cannot find the solution or why the exception is being thrown. I have quadruple checked the spelling, quadruple checked the case and quadruple checked the namespacing. The error I get is the following:

`ReflectionException in Container.php line 731: Class App\Repositories\ProductRepository does not exist`

The controller ProductController.php looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Repositories\ProductRepository;

class ProductsController extends Controller
{


protected $product;

public function __construct(ProductRepository $product){

    $this->product = $product;

}

//Other Methods...
}
```

The repository ProductRepository.php is in:

`App\Repositories`

and looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Repositories;

class ProductRepository {

public function getProducts(){
//Some Query
}

}
```

I've scoured every Laravel forum and Stack for the answer but none of the solutions have worked. I've been hours trying to find a solution and I simply cannot fathom how the class is not being recognised. Any ideas what I could be missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any error here, so it's possible you should run

```
composer dump-autoload
```

to make sure your class is visible.

Maybe you should also remove some cache using

```
php artisan clear-compiled
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've ran `composer dump-autoload`, `php artisan cache:clear` and `php artisan clear-compiled` about 100 times in the last hour. Nothing works.

Comment: @BillDukelow Any chance that you have white spaces in file name? For example at the beginning or at the end of file ? Look for typos, try to create file again

Comment: Ya I just checked and there are no spaces. I just deleted the Repositories directory and recreated the directory and file again. Still the same error.

Comment: @BillDukelow Do you have standard composer.json ? Have you not added some custom ServiceProvider that could break anything? It's really hard to say what's going on without full code

Comment: No i've not added any custom service providers yet. Thanks for your response. I think i'm just going to have to tinker a little more to try and debug.

Comment: No I didn't. I ran a fresh install of L5.4 and the copied the repo and controller over. It's working on this so it must be some 3rd party SP that was interfering. I wasn't prepared to look for it as it would have been a needle in a haystack situation and i'm a bit pressed for time. I'll go back when I have the time to look and see what the cause was.

Comment: Found the problem. Its an issue with an improper exception being thrown by Laravel. I had a typo in a ternary operator inside one of the Repo's methods that wasn't being flagged in my editor. This typo caused Laravel to throw an exception saying the file couldn't be found instead of a syntax exception like it should have.